# Degeneracy and the "Linear Degeneracy Testing" problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, discrete-geometry, algorithms, computational-complexity

The Affine Degeneracy problem is about deciding whether $n$ given points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (or $\mathbb{Q}^d$) are "in general position". i.e. there is no $d+1$ tuple of points which lies in a $d-1$ dimensional hyper-surface.

This problem is obviously very hard. For example, J. Erickson and R. Seidel in "Better Lower Bounds on Detecting Affine and Spherical Degeneracies" proved a lower bound complexity of $\Omega(n^d)$ on the geometry decision-tree model.

Interestingly, I've found that there is another problem, named as "Linear Degeneracy Testing" (LDT), which is widely claimed to be closely related to the Affine Degeneracy problem, but has a smaller decision-tree complexity because it reduces to a easier Subset Sum problem (still NP-Complete, though).

The Linear Degeneracy Testing problem can be formulated as follows:

> Given a $d$-variate linear function $f(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_d)=a_1t_1+a_2t_2+\ldots+a_dt_d$ with each $a_i$ being constant and $n$ numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$. Decide whether there is a $d$-tuple of distinct $(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_d)$ such that $f(x_{i_1},x_{i_2},\ldots,x_{i_d})=0$.

On the other hand, despite of the widely held claim, I failed to establish any non-trivial reduction from the Affine Degeneracy problem to the so-called "Linear Degeneracy Testing" problem. N. Ailon and B. Chazelle in "Lower Bounds for Linear Degeneracy Testing" once wrote

> For example, general position of $N$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be reduced to $d(d + 1)$-variate degeneracy testing with respect to $dn$ numbers; in this case, $f$ is a $(d+1)$-by-$(d+1)$ determinant with a row of ones.

However, this reduction **cannot be used** because a $(d+1)$-by-$(d+1)$ determinant is **not a linear function** and thus the reduction **does not** give a valid LDT instance.

I wonder:

- Is there any non-trivial reduction from Affine Degeneracy problem to the LDT problem?

> By *non-trivial* I mean an explicit reduction which maps the parameter space in a reasonable manner, instead of resorting to *"since LDT is proven NP-Complete, all NP problems reduce to it, e.g., via encoding an equivalent SAT or something"*-style argument.

- If there is not, what kind of "degeneracy" the "Linear Degeneracy Testing" problem is supposed to test? I think there should be a reason that it is called *"Linear Degeneracy Testing"* problem instead of *"Weighted Subset Sum"* problem (which I do believe should be a better name for LDT).

In the low dimensional special case, for example, the 3-POL problem which decides whether there are 3 points (among $n$ given points) lie in the same line, has complexity $O(n^2)$, which agrees with the 3-SUM or 3-LDT (they are essentially the same thing). On the other hand, there are some significant improvement made on the decision-tree complexity of 3-SUM, while at the 3-POL side those improvements are largely out of reach, which suggests that there may be some substantial differences between these 2 families of problems. It also seems rather unclear to me whether one can gain some advantage in solving k-POL given access to a k-SUM oracle.

Any references on this topic is also much appreciated.